# Modal Popup button click not fired second time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Modal Popup with dynamic controls. I need to add new text box in Button click.

**JQuery:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         if($('#hdnclick').val()==1){          
        $('#modelPopup').dialog({
     autoopen:false,     
     title: "Add New Server",
     width:650,
     height:450,
     modal:true,        
     buttons:{    
      Close:function(){
      $(this).dialog('close');      
      }
     }     
     });                
          $('#btnadd').click(function(){
            alert('okay');
          });
        }
    });

    </script>
```

**Aspx Code:-**

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdservices" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
          <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S.No" HeaderText="s.no" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="service name">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtservicename" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="description">
    <ItemTemplate>                                    
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="right" />
    <FooterTemplate>    
   <asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="add new service" OnClick="btnadd_Click" OnRowCommand="ButtonClicked" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
/asp:GridView>
```

My Issue is this "btnAddNewServic_Click" button click fired in first click but this "btnAddNewServic_Click" function not fired in second click even anything is not fired in second click. Can anyone one help me to recover this issue..

**Output:**
[image]

**Adding New Rows:-**

```
 protected void grdServices_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "ButtonClicked")
            {
                hdnclick.Value = "1";
                AddNewRowToGrid();
            }
        }


private void AddNewRowToGrid()
        {
            int rowindex = 0;
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TextBox Box1 = (TextBox)grdservices.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtservicename");
                        TextBox Box2 = (TextBox)grdservices.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtDescription");

                        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                        drCurrentRow["S.No"] = i + 1;

                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = Box1.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = Box2.Text;

                        rowindex++;
                    }
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                    grdservices.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                    grdservices.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: show us the code where you are adding the new button or row.

Comment: I added the code where i was adding the new row..

Comment: where is the button in the code you are not adding the button in the code plz add it and it will work

Comment: I added a button called "btnadd" inside the gridview @Cracker

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.CommandName == "ButtonClicked")
      {
          //Do Stuff
      }
  }
```

Add RowCommand To Button and use above code to get the "ButtonClicked" command and add the columns to the grid view using your methods

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564619/Example-of-gridview-rowcommand-on-Button-Click)

Comment: I was add OnRowCommand in my aspx page. but that modal popup doesn't trigger anything to codebehind.. I need to solve this @cracker.

Comment: Please remove OnClick="btnadd_Click" from button

Comment: I removed Onclick="btnadd_Click" and add this OnRowCommand="ButtonClicked".. Its fired but not satisfy this condition  if (e.CommandName == "ButtonClicked").. It returns ""

Comment: @dinesh.k refer the new Reference link and you will get how to use it

Comment: I missed Command Name ="ButtonClicked"..But @Cracker in my second click its not trigger because of modal popup.. Any idea

Comment: i think you need to use Ajax ModalPopupExtender in this instead of using this jquery pop. it will be easy and help you to get easy post back.

Answer (score 0):

Put a Class name for the button control

```
<asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="add new service" OnClick="btnadd_Click" OnRowCommand="ButtonClicked" class="btnAdd" />
```

use this class name as for the click event fire like

```
$('#btnadd').click(function(){
            alert('okay');
          });
```

to change the below on

```
$('.btnadd').click(function(){
            alert('okay');
          });
```

and you should check page is load if the gird items is load again. I think that one is issue by **rendering a control**, because you create a control dynamically so you should check that one also.